# Radical of modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-representations, modules, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a local ring with the unique maximal ideal ${\frak m}_R$ and $M$ be a $R$-module. Define

$I(M) \colon= \cap ~({\mathrm{all~ proper~ maximal ~submodules~ of}}~M)$,

where proper means strictly smaller than $M$. Then,

### Q. Why does the inclusion ${\frak m}_RM \subset I(M)$ hold ?

Comment: This follows from basic properties of the Jacobson radical (it's true for arbitrary rings $R$ if you replace the maximal ideal by the Jacobson radical $J(R)$, see Lam, *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*, Prop. 24.4). This question is certainly not research level.

Answer (score 2):

A more general statement than this actually holds. If $J$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$ (i.e. the intersection of all the maximal ideals of $R$, or just the radical of $R$ as a left module over itself), then $JM \subseteq \operatorname{Rad} M$. Of course, in the local case, this reduces to your question.

First, note that $J$ annihilates all simple left $R$-modules by Nakayama's Lemma. Indeed, if $S$ is such module, then Nakayama implies that $JS \subsetneq S$, so $JS = 0$. Second, there is a semisimple $R$-module $T$ which surjects onto $M/\operatorname{Rad}M$. Take, for instance, 
$$T = \bigoplus_{A \subseteq M \text{ maximal}} M/A,$$
where the surjection is induced by the quotient maps $M/A \rightarrow M/\operatorname{Rad} M$.

Now, since $J$ annihilates $T$, it annihilates $M/\operatorname{Rad}M$, as well. It follows that $JM \subseteq \operatorname{Rad}M$.

Depending on your interests, there may be better references for this sort of thing, but Chapter I of Assem, Simson, Skowronski (easier to read) or Section 15 of Anderson-Fuller (more thorough) are both good references on the zillions of ways to use the Jacobson radical.

*Ibrahim Assem, Daniel Simson, and Andrzej Skowronski*, MR 2197389 [**Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras. Vol. 1**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511614309), ISBN: 978-0-521-58423-4; 978-0-521-58631-3; 0-521-58631-3.

*Anderson, Frank W., and Kent R. Fuller*, [**Rings and Categories of Modules**](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387978451), New York: Springer-Verlag, 1992. Print.

Comment: Great thanks! Good explanation. Pierre